# Show a banner when a post has already completed review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

I was reviewing Triage when I came upon [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7921397). By the time I reviewed it, it was *already closed*, so I couldn't flag it normally. I would have skipped, but I thought it was a review audit, so I flagged with a custom flag. Immediately afterwards, when the audit pass/fail screen didn't show, I realized what had happened, so I'm writing this to ask for a banner or other notification that an item has been reviewed since it was shown to you.

This would help prevent people from using custom moderator flags in the event that they didn't realize what was going on, like in my case. Then the reviewer could know to click 'Skip'.

It wouldn't be all that commonly used, but since it seems that this has happened in at least one other case, it's at least worth noting.

Comment: I had the exact same experience (right down to using a custom flag because I thought it was a review), so this isn't an isolated incident.

Comment: @seaotternerd Was this in the Triage queue? If it wasn't, I'm gonna remove the [tag:triage] tag

Comment: Yes, it was. That's why I couldn't just downvote (since it was clearly unsalvageable).

Comment: Oh, good point. Triage is the only queue where you're required to flag or say it looks okay.

Comment: @QPays There are more than two options. You can do "should be improved" or "skip". Also, so you're saying you went to flag to close it, but it gave a message saying it's already been closed? Did you try refreshing the page then? B.c normally it will then say correctly that "this review is no longer able to be reviewed".. So just saying it may not be a bug if the question was closed during the time after you were given the review and before you flagged to close it

Comment: I didn't get a message saying it was closed. I only know that it was already closed because I was so concerned by it (like I said, it was highly unsalvageable) that I opened it in a separate tab to leave a comment, and when I switched to that tab after completing my review, I saw the "This question was removed" page. It's entirely possible that it was closed after I received it in the review queue, but there was no notification on the review page that that had occurred.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Like I say in the question, I thought this was an audit, so I flagged. If is known it had simply already been reviewed, I would have skipped. That's why I suggest some sort of notification that it's already been reviewed. Also, I was exaggerating slightly, but in the case of review audits there are really only two options, and this was a decently clear-cut case of flagging.

Comment: I think this may be more of a feature-request  to notify reviewer that post is no longer reviewable while on that review without having to refresh. Since this "bug" is very small in that most people do reviews fairly quickly so it doesn't happen *too often* that you try to act on a review that just recently < 1 minute usually has became unavailable.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 If you think so, feel free to edit it in. Rereading, it does seem more like a feature request than a bug, but I'm unable to edit on the app. It keeps crashing intermittently.